# How do I store user data in Android and make it persistent even in case of App Updates?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sdcard

I have an application (which is designed to **work offline**) where a large number of entries  are stored in a database and user entered values are stored against each of the entries in one of the columns in the databases. The user modifies only these values when he uses the App.

But when I push an **app update**, the **user loses all the values he entered** against them. How do I solve the issue ? (I also want the database to be private to the Android Application).

Comment: One solution is to write the user changes to an another public external database with reference to id of this database, so when the App is uninstalled the external database will persist and I can have a logic to restore when the new version app is run for the first time. Is this the best possible solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a DB like this:

```
  /**
     * Open the test database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public TestDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbVersionWebiDBAdapter = mDbHelper.dbVersion;
    return this;
    }
```

This works very nicely and any update can pick up on the data. You may also use some kind of DB versioning so you can update the database easily with new updates.

This DB will only be deleted if the user goes to the settings menu and deinstalls the app there - or the data. An update load of an app will keep the database.